# Inconsistent Ohr HaChaim?

Tags: genesis-bereishith, adam, genealogy, noach-noah-the-man

In [this Ohr HaChaim](https://www.sefaria.org/Or_HaChaim_on_Genesis.49.3?lang=bi#:%7E:text=%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9D%20%D7%A9%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%9C%20%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%97%20%D7%A9%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%9C%20%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9A%20%D7%A9%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%9C%20%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F) he says that Noach received the pre sinatic torah from Chanoch (Enoch) who had received it from Adam.

From my understanding Noach was born after Chanochs death.

This would seem to make it difficult for Chanoch to have transmitted anything to Noach since Noach was not alive during the time of Chanoch.

Comment: Chanoch was "taken away" when he was 365 years old in ~987, indeed before Noach was born in the year 1056, but he didn't die. There is the Book of Chanoch, which the Zohar records Noach had. Not sure if related.

Comment: @RabbiKaii Thank you for the updated info, and i updated my question accordingly.

Comment: No problem, thanks very much for introducing us to this amazing Or HaChaim

Answer (score 4):

The details of the transmission of this Torah is recounted in the opening pages of [Sefer Raziel HaMalach](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=66917&st=&pgnum=11).

The book of Chanoch was hidden away during his lifetime because his contemporaries and the generations which followed did not merit to receive it.

Noach was judged worthy in his generation and in his 500th year, the angel, Rafoel was sent to reveal the book to him.

Comment: Shame they didn't send Metatron to teach him? :)